# SharePoint List Column Calculation formular with conditional Calculation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am working on a fuel issuance list in SharePoint online with 3 different vehicle engines.

Using the columns given below:

- Requester Name: (Name Field)
- Vehicle Location (Dropdown List)
- Vehicle Registration (Dropdown List)
- Previous-KM (Number field)
- Current-KM (Number field)
- Diff-KM   (calculated field)
- Vehicle-Model (Dropdown List)
- K/Liter (Number field) Hidden
- Fuel Pump (Calculated Field)

I want the Diff KM should be divided by a selected vehicle type on the drop-down list.

***Vehicle Models & their Calculations:***

TOYOTA PRADO             8Km/Liter,

TOYOTA LANDCRUISER LC200 7Km/Liter,

TOYOTA LANDCRUISER       7Km/Liter,

TOYOTA LANDCRUISER 79    7Km/Liter,

TOYOTA HILUX             9km/Liter,

TOYOTA HIACE Minibus     9Km/Liter

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

see error below after using the last formula
[image]

[image]

I used this  code on the JSON section but calculate for only one see screenshot below
[image]

IF(
OR([Vehicle Model]="TOYATA LANDCRUISER",[KM/Liter]="7",

```
IF(
    OR([Vehicle Model]="TOYOTA PRADO ",[KM/Liter]="8",
    IF(
        OR([Vehicle Model]="TOYOTA HIACE ",[KM/Liter]="9"),
        
        IF(
            OR([Vehicle Model]="TOYOTA HILUX" ,[KM/Liter]="9"),
            
            
        )
    )
)
```

)

Comment: urgently looking for a technical support for this post

Comment: Where is the Vehicle Type in screenshot? Is this a choice column, if yes what are the choice options? What is the current formula you are using for Diff KM? Can you mention all the required conditions in your question?

Comment: hello Ganesh, the vehicle type has been changed to "Vehicle Model" and its a choice column with a dropdown list.  when you take a look at the post you will see it

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the Vehicle Model column, the entire list and the Diff-KM formula

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could create a calculated column named Diff KM then use below formula:

```
=IF([Vehicle type]="1","test1",IF([Vehicle type]="2","test2","test3"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh, I think you did not get my question clearly. let's provide all the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh, for your prompt response.  let's provide all the necessary information.  the Diff KM column should be divided by the KM/Liter which is a hidden lookup column when the user chooses from the dropdown list VEHICLE MODEL and then provided the litres of fuel pump as per the screenshot above

Comment: we can go to the chat room for a better explanation.  at your local time always ready

Comment: Hello,
The formula that I need is that the “Diff-KM”  reading should be divided by KM/Liter based on  the “Vehicle model” chosen  and to provide the number of liters of “Fuel Pump”
• I have 6 different Vehicle models 
TOYOTA PRADO    8 KM/L,
TOYOTA HIACE Minibus 9KM/L, 
TOYOTA LANDCRUISER LC200 7KM/L,   
TOYOTA LANDCRUISER    7KM/L,  
TOYOTA LANDCRUISER 79 7KM/L,    
TOYOTA HILUX      9KM/L,    

• I have  A number column  (KM/LITER ) 7,8,9  KM/Liter to be  auto select from and should be a (hidden column)
Please help

Answer (score 0):

As you have `KM/Liter` column in your list for each row (vehicle model), you can use below calculated formula for `Diff-KM` column:

```
=([Current KM]-[Previous KM])/[KM/Liter]
```

For safer side to avoid divided by 0 or any other error, you can use formula like:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([KM/Liter]), [KM/Liter] = 0), 0, ([Current KM]-[Previous KM])/[KM/Liter])
```

In place of 2nd `0` in above formula, you can write any default value/expression as per your requirement.

---

**Or** use this better version:

```
=ROUND(IF(OR(ISBLANK([KM/Liter]),[KM/Liter]=0),0,([Current KM]-[Previous KM])/[KM/Liter]),2)
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: which Column should have the formula? there is only  one column for (Vehicle Model)

Comment: Formula should be for `Diff-KM` - calculated column.

Comment: am having 0 reading from the   Diff-KM column  and 0 Fuel pump

Comment: Does this work? `=ROUND(IF(OR(ISBLANK([KM/Liter]),[KM/Liter]=0),[Current KM]-[Previous KM],([Current KM]-[Previous KM])/[KM/Liter]),2)`

Comment: it brings the Diff-KM but cannot divide the from the KM/Liter to get the Fuel-Pump value

Comment: on the above screenshot the 300 is the current input